# Horizontal Tabs and displaying content with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to figure out why my horizontal tabs are not working. I can get the content to display, however it is always the test1 content under .test_content -> .test_tabbed_content -> .pages/test1.html no matter which link I click. I believe there is something wrong with the code, and either I'm glancing over it or just completely oblivious.

EDITED CODE TO REFLECT CSS

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $(".tabbed_content").click(function() {
      $(".test_tabbed_content").show("slow");
      var val = $(this).find("a").attr('name');
      $("#" + val).show("slow");
    });
  });
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Poppins";
  src: url("../Font/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.woff") format('woff');
  font-weight: 600;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test_main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.test_header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 0% 0%, #373b52, #252736 51%, #1d1e26);
}

.test_logo {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.test_logo span {
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-top: 1.75%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.test_logo img {
  width: 1vw;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-top: 1.75%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.test_tabs {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.arrow_left,
.arrow_right {
  font-size: 2vh;
  color: #ef0003;
}

.arrow_left:hover,
.arrow_right:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.arrow_cont_left {
  width: 1.5%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  background: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.arrow_button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow_cont_right {
  width: 1.5%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  background: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabbed {
  width: 97%;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  overflow-y;
  hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.tabbed_content {
  width: 5vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: #00afef;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

.tabbed_button:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  bottom-border: 1px solid red;
}

.tabbed_content span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1vh;
  background: inherit;
}

.tabbed_button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.test_content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 97%;
  background: inherit;
}

.test_tabbed_content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.external_object {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test_main">
  <div class="test_header">
    <div class="test_logo">
      <span> Test</span><img src="../Media/test.png">
    </div>
    <div class="test_tabs">
      <a class="arrow_button">
        <div class="arrow_cont_left"><span class="arrow_left">&lt;</span></div>
      </a>
      <div class="tabbed">
        <div class="tabbed_content"><a class="tabbed_button" name="test1"><span>Test1</span></a></div>
        <div class="tabbed_content"><a class="tabbed_button" name="test2"><span>Test2</span></a></div>
      </div>
      <a class="arrow_button">
        <div class="arrow_cont_right"><span class="arrow_right">&gt;</span></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test_content">
    <div class="test_tabbed_content" id="test1"><object data="pages/test1.html" class="external_object"></object></div>
    <div class="test_tabbed_content" id="test2"><object data="pages/test2.html" class="external_object"></object></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: .. A couple of things. Can we please have your `CSS` to make this visually easier. Also, `<img src="../Media/test.png">` isn't closed, it needs to be `<img src="../Media/test.png"/>`. Also `.show("slow");` doesn't seem to make any sense because as far as I can tell, there's no object `slow` defined?

Comment: @EGC slow is a parameter in Javascript for the speed of showing an object. The content is originally set to display: none, which upon a link click, it shows the content slowly.

Comment: Do you have any console errors when you hit `f12` and interact with the solution?

Comment: @EGC there are no errors when I hit F12 in the browser.

Comment: Could you please provide the code where the parameter is passed into the function? Because the onclick function provided obviously has no concept of this paramater. Having as much code as possible, especially in regard to passing parameters may be essential for solving this

Comment: the onclick parameter definitely works, as it loads the content in the tabbed content, where first it doesn't. The only thing is it is loading test1.html for no matter which click. it won't load the content relevant to the click.

Comment: Maybe? https://jsfiddle.net/ku3vgm21/